# Windows routing without gateway (but through interface). Is it possible?

Tags: windows, routing, ip-routing

I have a custom network setup. My servers have what I would call "main IP" with gateway for example:

> Main IP: 67.166.214.148
>
> Netmask: 255.255.255.0
>
> Gateway: 67.166.214.1

And then I have additional IP addresses which are routed to the server through its main IP, such as:

> Additional: 66.249.70.2
>
> Netmask: 255.255.255.255

and then basically my router has a static or BGP route something like `ip route 66.249.70.2 255.255.255.255 67.166.214.148`)

I can reach outside world through additional IP on my host with no issues, but it is a little tricky when it comes to using additional IP that way on virtual machines inside the host.

On linux vm I can do:

```
ip ro default via 67.166.214.1

ip ro add 67.166.214.1 dev eth0
```

(so basically it tells that `67.166.214.1` is reachable through `eth0(bridged)` device and then the host server forwards it to the router and it works)

I can not recreate this on windows virtual machine. Is there a way I could tell my windows virtual machine to use the NIC device as gateway itself like it is possible on Linux? Or use some workaround.

Comment: route print, and route add does not help in your case ?

Comment: I toyed around with route add in windows, however, it does not allow a route to be added without gateway IP address specified.

I can specify default route via 67.166.214.1, but when I try to specify where 67.166.214.1 itself is reachable I still need a gateway IP. Some people suggested using something like gateway as 0.0.0.0 with specified NIC (with "if" option), however, it has no effect. 
route -p add 67.166.214.1 mask 255.255.255.0 0.0.0.0 if 12